# Sendgrid in Vercel not sending email in production

Tags: node.js, next.js, sendgrid, vercel

I'm using SendGrid to send emails in my serverless Next.js project, deployed in Vercel, which works perfectly in development mode. But I'm having problems in production.

The error returned is:

```
contact-us-4c7332c1e7bfe2127d39.js:1 POST https://mywebsite.vercel.app/api/send 400
```

Yes, I enabled "Allow Less Secured Apps" in Google account and verify a Sender Identity in SendGrid.

Anybody experienced this kind of problem? How can I fix this?

This is the **contact-us.js** page

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export default () => {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState({
    submitted: false,
    submitting: false,
    info: { error: false, msg: null }
  })

  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
    name: '',
    phone: '',
    email: '',
    message: ''
  })

  function SubmitButton(){
    if (inputs.name && inputs.email && inputs.message) {
      return <button type="submit" className="btn-submit" disabled={status.submitting}> {!status.submitting ? !status.submitted ? 'Submit' : 'Submitted' : 'Submitting...'} </button>
    } else {
      return <button type="submit" className="btn-submit" disabled>Submit</button>
    };
  };

  const handleResponse = (status, msg) => {
    if (status === 200) {
      setStatus({
        submitted: true,
        submitting: false,
        info: { error: false, msg: msg }
      })
      setInputs({
        name: '',
        phone: '',
        email: '',
        message: ''
      })
    } else {
      setStatus({
        info: { error: true, msg: msg }
      })
    }
  }

  const handleOnChange = e => {
    e.persist()
    setInputs(prev => ({
      ...prev,
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    }))
    setStatus({
      submitted: false,
      submitting: false,
      info: { error: false, msg: null }
    })
  }

  const handleOnSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setStatus(prevStatus => ({ ...prevStatus, submitting: true }))
    const res = await fetch('/api/send', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(inputs)
    })
    const text = await res.text()
    handleResponse(res.status, text)
  }

  return (
    <div className="contact">
      <main>
        <div>
          <h2>Get in touch!</h2>
          <h3>How can we help you?</h3>
        </div>
        <form onSubmit={handleOnSubmit}>
          
          <div className="form-group">
            <input
              id="name"
              type="text"
              name="name" 
              onChange={handleOnChange}
              required
              value={inputs.name}
              className={inputs.name ? "form-control active" : "form-control"}
            />
            <label className="form-label" htmlFor="name">Name</label>
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <input
              id="email"
              type="text"
              name="email" 
              onChange={handleOnChange}
              required
              value={inputs.email}
              className={inputs.email ? "form-control active" : "form-control"}
            />
            <label className="form-label" htmlFor="email">Email</label>
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <input
              id="phone"
              type="tel"
              name="phone" 
              onChange={handleOnChange}
              required
              value={inputs.phone}
              className={inputs.phone ? "form-control active" : "form-control"}
            />
            <label className="form-label" htmlFor="phone">Phone</label>
          </div>
          
          <div className="form-group">
            <textarea
              id="message"
              onChange={handleOnChange}
              required
              value={inputs.message}
              className={inputs.message ? "form-control active" : "form-control"}
            />
            <label className="form-label" htmlFor="message">Message</label>
          </div>

          <SubmitButton />

          {status.info.error && (
          <div className="message-feedback error">
            <p>Error: {status.info.msg}</p>
          </div>
          )}
          {!status.info.error && status.info.msg && (
            <div className="message-feedback success">
              <p>Thanks for messaging us!</p>
              <p>We'll get back to you soon.</p>
            </div>
          )}
        </form>
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}
```

And the **/api/send.js**

```
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail')

export default async function(req, res) {
  sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY)

  const { phone, email, message } = req.body

  const msg = {
    to: 'myemail@outlook.com', // Change to your recipient
    from: 'mysenderemail@gmail.com', // Change to your verified sender
    subject: `New Message From - ${email}`,
    text: message,
    html: `
      <p>Phone: ${phone}</p>
      <p>Sent from: ${email}</p>
      <div>${message}</div>
    `
  }

  try {
    await sgMail.send(msg)
    res.status(200).send('Message sent successfully.')
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('ERROR', error)
    res.status(400).send('Message not sent.')
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: If you `console.log(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY)`, do you see a value in production?

Comment: No, it's not defined, but I tried with the real API key instead of .env and works...

Comment: ok, then the issue is that your `SENDGRID_API_KEY` [environment-variable](https://vercel.com/docs/projects/environment-variables) is not set up in production

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!